# How to add custom prefix to 3rd party CSS classes with Webpack/PostCSS?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, webpack, postcss, webpacker

I am using [Webpacker](https://github.com/rails/webpacker) to build assets for a Rails app. I want to add custom prefixes to all of the class names coming from 3rd party CSS frameworks. For example, the styles from [Bulma](https://bulma.io/) should be transformed to use `bulma_button` as a selector instead of just `button`.

[`postcss-prefixer`](https://github.com/marceloucker/postcss-prefixer) is a PostCSS plugin that appears to add custom prefixes to stylesheets like I want. However, I still need to make it only prefix the classes coming from a specific NPM package.

This is where I am stuck on my path to prefixing the 3rd party styles: How can I apply a PostCSS plugin only to a certain `node_modules` directory and import the results into my entry point stylesheet? I have tried breaking up the loader pipeline provided by Webpacker and manipulating the `test`/`include`/`exclude` Webpack config values, but it seems I can only successfully impact the entire stylesheet that gets compiled including my styles that I do not want to prefix.

Any help on the specific PostCSS plugin problem or the overall goal of prefixing 3rd party CSS is appreciated. I will link to a sample app if it is considered useful.